# Converting Nonlinear Program into an LP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I have a problem with a nonlinear objective function which is

\begin{align}\min&\quad Z_j\cdot(N_j)^{0.5}\end{align} where $j$ is the index.

I want to know how can I turn it into a linear programming problem.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! Can you provide more information? What are $Z_j$ and $N_j$? Are they binary and continuous? Are they both continuous? Also, you can format your question better by using [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site)

Comment: In addition to questions by @EhsanK, what constraints if any are there?

Comment: Also, are $Z,N$ both optimization variables? Are they matrices?

Comment: Z is a binary variable and Nj is the summation of Xij on i which X is also a binary variable( which makes the N an integer). This is actually an uncapacitated facility location problem and the part I wrote is the setup cost.